# How to convert a String to Integer and test it?

Tags: php, string, integer, type-conversion

I've a problem. I'm scrapping a txt file and extracting an ID. The problem is that the data is not consistent and I have to evaluate the data.

Here is some code:

```
$a = "34";
$b = " 45";
$c = "ddd556z";


if (  ) {

    echo "INTEGER";
} else{ 

    echo "STRING";
}
```

I need test if the values $a, $b or $c are Integers. What is the best way of doing this? I have tested to "trim" and the use "is_int" but is not working as expected.

Can someone give me some clues?

Comment: as your data are all strings in this example you will show false when using is_int($a) (or $b or $c)

What results are you expecting? $a and $b to be true? Then either cast to an int or use is_numeric() however note that floats, doubles and numbers using scientific notation will also show as true using is_numeric().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example below will work even if your "int" is a string `$a = "number";`

```
is_numeric()
```

or

```
preg_match( '/^-?[0-9]+$/' , $var )  // negative number © Piskvor
```

or

```
intval($var) == $var
```

or (same as last)

```
(int) $var == $var
```

Comment: Only the example with preg will not validate -1. All other will.

Comment: @yes123: [Integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer). Note the part about negative numbers - the OP didn't specify "positive integers", did he? ( `/^-?[0-9]+$/` would work)

Comment: @piskvor: I have wrote 4 example. Only the preg doens't match the negative number. do you think it is enough to give a -1? ... anyway I have added your solution in my answer. +1 to you

Comment: @yes123: "Part of my answer is wrong, so what?" Well, that's definitely worthy of the highest negative integer.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php

```
<?php
$strings = array('1820.20', '10002', 'wsl!12');
foreach ($strings as $testcase) {
    if (ctype_digit($testcase)) {
        echo "The string $testcase consists of all digits.\n";
    } else {
        echo "The string $testcase does not consist of all digits.\n";
    }
}

// will output
//The string 1820.20 does not consist of all digits.
//The string 10002 consists of all digits.
//The string wsl!12 does not consist of all digits.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
$a = 34;
if (is_int($a)) {
    echo "is integer";
} else {
    echo "is not an integer";
}
?>
```

> ```
> $a="34";
> ```

will not validate as int ;)